# Excel: Appending values in columns

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet in this format:

```
 A   B           C
 11  Trailers   Trailer Builders
 19  Trailers   Erde Trailers
```

I'd like to append every value in the column B with the following characters ->, I'd also like append every value in the column C with a $. What is the best solution for this in Excel?

My output should look like this:

```
     A   B           C
     11  Trailers->  Trailer Builders$
     19  Trailers->  Erde Trailers$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do D2 as `=CONCATENATE(B2,"->")` and E2 as `=CONCATENATE(C2,"$",)` to get this value.